# Yii2 - set response headers in action

Tags: php, yii2

In my action I am doing it like this:

```
public function actionEvents(){
        Yii::$app->response->headers->set('last-modified','2020-01-19');
        return $this->modelClass::find()->all();
    }
```

I also tried it like:

```
Yii::$app->response->headers->set('last-modified',(date_format('2020-01-19','Y/m/d H:i:s')));
```

but I am getting the entry for `last-modifed`, which was not there altogether, but the date I am getting is like

`last-modified: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`

when I am using `2020-01-19` and when I am using `date_format` I am getting 500 error.

How I can fix this.

update:
I could see cache control header is coming like this:

`cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate`

could this be the reason, for `last-modified` is not getting correct date.
How I can set the cache control to say 1 minute.

**update:**
image of response header
[image]

**related action code:**

```
public function actionEvents(){
     $dateModified = '2020-01-19';
    $date = new \DateTime($dateModified);   
    Yii::$app->response->headers->set('last-modified', date_format($date, 'Y/m/d H:i:s'));     
        return $this->modelClass::find()->all();
    }
```

Note: The URL action in question is API endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

You are using string whereas you should pass `DateTimeInterface` as the first parameter of `date_format` otherwise it raises warning change it to

```
$dateModified = '2020-01-19';
$date = new DateTime($dateModified);

Yii::$app->response->headers->set('last-modified', date_format($date, 'Y/m/d H:i:s'));
```

Comment: Hi Omer - I replaced the code as per your suggestion, but I am still getting the `last-modified` as `last-modified: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`. an additional note I am trying the same in action using API json response;

Comment: where are you watching the headers, you should look inti the response headers not request @Joshi if i wrap the above code into an action, with a line `return "hello";` at the end it shows this https://imgur.com/AL3DvpG

Comment: Hi Omer - I am looking at `response header` only, see image and related action code - updated in question.

Comment: Hi Omer - can you please look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59897322/yii2-mogodb-rbac-configuration

Answer (score 0):

I tried every possible combination to make it work as suggested by @Muhammad Omer Aslam, but it didn't worked for me.

after that basing on this link - https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/caching-http, I modified that a little, which worked for me.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\HttpCache',
            'only' => ['index','events'],
            'lastModified' => function ($action, $params) {
                $q = new \yii\db\Query();
                return strtotime($q->from('event_calendar')->max('updated_at'));
            },
        ],
    ];
}
```

so from the referred link I just wrapped the below code with `strtotime` and changed db table name, which worked fine for me.

```
return s$q->from('posts')->max('updated_at');
```